# average probability for an edge be a in random spanning tree of a weighted graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-walks, spanning-tree

any cofactor of a Laplacian of a weighted graph will give the sum of all weighted spanning trees, lets denote it by $A$. The same can be calculated for spanning trees which avoid certain edge $e$, denote it by $A_e$. There, $P[e \in T]=1-\frac{A_e}{A}$, the probability that an edge $e$ being part of a random spanning tree.
I would like to calculate the average probability of an edge $e$ being part of a random spanning tree of a weighted graph. 
Would be glad for any help.
 
Thank you!

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/100209/probability-of-an-edge-appearing-in-a-spanning-tree?rq=1 is quite a similar question.

Comment: I'm looking for an average probability.

Comment: Average over what?  Do you mean average over $e$?

Comment: Average over all $P_e $

Comment: If $P_e$ is what you called $P[e\in T]$, that is just a number.  What probability space do you want to average it over?

Comment: Yes , over all edges

Comment: What does the weighting have to do with anything?

Comment: You need to rewrite your question, giving an explicit formula for the quantity you want to calculate.  As you can see, we are not clear on what you mean.